# Switching from surfaceview to main activity class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, surfaceview

I have an activity which uses a surfaceview as its content view to draw some bitmaps and carry out animations, what is the best way to control starting a new round event to load a new set of bitmaps for the next round within this surfaceview thread or what is the best way to switch from a surfaceview thread, back to the main game activity after a round is done. What I have tried so far, below is a snippet from the surfaceview class where everything is drawn.

```
              if(isCollided(i)){

            if(imgList.indexOf(imgList.get(i)) == 0){

                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(context, AnimeAction.class);
                            context.startActivity(i);
                        }});


            }
```

Comment: you don't want to use new Intent(this,main_activity)??

Comment: i have tried this of course, but resulted in a crash after, thanks for your reply

Comment: what was the error in logcat? can you paste it in your post along with the code?

Comment: it was unexpected null exception pointer, also i had used finish after calling the new intent

Comment: edited the main question with a snippet

Comment: where is the above code written? I mean in which function? and what about the context here? Have you initialized it?

Comment: yes this is within the drawing method which draws bitmaps to the screen. context is passed from the main activity as "this".

Comment: how have you declared activity? can you show that? If you show more of your code, it would be helpful.

Comment: MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do this :

```
MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
```

Instead try this :

```
MainActivity activity = MainActivity.this;
```

As far as posting a new set of bitmaps is concerned, I have done it like this in my app :

```
public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable
    {
        Thread t=null;
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        boolean ok;

        public OurView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            holder=getHolder();

        }
        public void run()
        {
                  //draw the bitmaps
                } 
            public void pause()
        {
            ok=false;
            Log.v("pause()", "ok=false");
            while(true)
            {
                try{

                    t.join();

                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    Log.v("pause()",e.toString());
                }

                break;
            }
           t=null;

        }
        public void resume()
        {
            ok=true;
            if(t==null)
            {
             t=new Thread(this);
               t.start();
               Log.v("resume()", "new thread started");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.v("resume()", "new thread not started as t!=null");
            }
        }
}
```

And in the Activity's `onResume()` and `onCreate()` :

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        Log.v("onPause()", "super.onPause()");
        v.pause();  //V IS AN OBJECT OF THE CLASS OurView

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Log.v("onResume()", "super.onResume()");
        v.resume();
      }
```

I learnt it from this video (and the subsequent one's 1.28 -1.33) - http://youtube.com/watch?v=Z2YogvILjvo